# UiPath Community Edition

Tags: licensing, uipath

I had installed UiPath trial version previously, and uninstalled it when the license expired. As I use this machine for testing, I wanted to install UiPath community edition. I downloaded it and installed. When I fire it up, it still says the license status is: Server license expired. How do I get community edition running.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The link to renew the community edition for UiPath Studio, which should also work for activating after the trial as expired, is: [Community Edition Renewal - UiPath Studio](https://www.uipath.com/renew-community-license)

Answer (score 4):

UiPath are quite sneaky in the fact that they don't tell you that you have to go to their [renewal site](https://www.uipath.com/renew-community-license) in order to renew the community license

Answer (score 4):

**About the problem**

UiPath do not allow users to switch from an Enterprise license to a Community Edition (CE) license, even after the trial has expired, without first contacting support. After you activate a device with an Enterprise license you are not permitted to use CE on the same device. It's not an error and it is actually the expected behaviour. When you activate Enterprise edition your device key is registered in the UiPath database, which prevents you from registering a CE license.

If you are experiencing this problem, it is likely that you have received the following output:

`Activation failed with error: 0
Error description: Cannot use Community Edition on this machine after activating a trial or Enterprise license code. Please enter a valid license key.
License status: Device ID already activated`

**Official solution**

UiPath state that only in special situations may the trial license be extended or the Device ID released from their licensing. They recommend you contact their support team to enquire about disabling the Enterprise license and you can do this [here](https://www.uipath.com/company/contact-us/licensing-queries-activations).

**A more useful workaround!!!**

However, there is another way that does not require you to contact support. This workaround involves using Orchestrator as the licensing server. Here is what you can do to begin using CE:

- ***Install [UiPath Community Edition](https://www.uipath.com/developers/community-edition-download)***
- ***Connect Studio (the Robot in user-mode that comes with Studio) to Orchestrator Community Edition: [https://platform.uipath.com/](https://platform.uipath.com) as Development Robot***
- ***Studio will get its license through Orchestrator (since 2018.4 version)***

Here are some additional resources that may be of use:

[Community Edition license agreement](https://www.uipath.com/developers/community-edition/license-agreement)

[UiPath Trial Agreement](https://www.uipath.com/hubfs/legalspot/UiPath_Trial_Terms.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

**use 2021.4.4 version**

Based on the *connection type* (**machine key / service URL**) you can connect both community / enterprise edition.

No need to get two different installation one for community another for enterprise.
This problem has been fixed with 2021.4.4

UiPath Assistance will help you to connect through your personal Orchestrator for community or organizational orchestrator for enterprise.